# jquery Ajax callback onchange from dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have a dropdownlist and Onchange I want to send an Ajax request to my controller, how can I get the actual data or the value of the selected dropdownlist selection to put into my Ajax callback.

```
$('#TypeFeed').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Account/changefeed",
                type: "GET",
                 // how can I get selected value here


            });
        });

 // This is my dropdownList below id=TypeFeed
@Html.DropDownList("TypeFeed", new SelectList(new List<Object>{
                new { Text = "Local Issues", Value = "Local Issues"},new { Text ="sports", Value= "sports"}}, "Value", "Text"))
```

I want to send the value here but must first capture it in the callback

```
public PartialViewResult changefeed(string TypeFeed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `val()` method to get the selected OPTION's value.

```
$(function(){

   $('#TypeFeed').change(function () {
     var typeFeed=$(this).val();
     //do ajax now
     $.get("@Url.Action("changefeed","Home")?TypeFeed="+typeFeed,function(res){
       //do something with res now
     });
   });

});
```

Consider encoding the value before sending it. You may use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) method.

You can send the selected item value this way too

```
     $.get("@Url.Action("changefeed","Home")",{ TypeFeed:typeFeed},function(res){
       //do something with res now
     });
```